# IIS get restart on file delete/store operation in server and losing session

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a file delete option for the files uploaded by the user, user can upload many files at a time.The uploaded files will be stored in a folder in server and when its is deleted its is moved to trash folder from where it will be manually cleared.

when a user tries to delete many files in the web page IIS get hangs and all session is expired. This case only present in server,in local host this issue is not available.

ALL the operations is carried out completely ie

- Database gets updated.
- Files is moved from upload folder to
  trash folder in server.

I cannot determine what is going wrong,I just tried to delete many files totally around 35-36 MB. Is the issue with process taking long or is there any changes have to be made in order to perform large files operation, my project is done on VS2005 which is running in 2008 server please help...

Comment: You're restarting the International Space Station? Jeepers!

Comment: @Ian Nelson - at first it was just a remote toilet flush, but that caused a stink.

Answer (score 3):

If you delete file/folder under your web site or virtual directory, your web application will be re-started resulting in wiping out all (in-process) sessions. Solution would be quite simple - make sure that you store your files outside your web site directory.

Comment: how to store files outside web site directory. Is hard path like "C:\\Projects\\uploadfiles" is what u meant. if so is it a vaild method to solve the issue, will there be any security issues..? pls help..

Comment: @Deepu, I would suggest to have path to your file store configurable (for example, read it from web.config). The account(s) under which ASP.NET code is running (can change based on your config) must have read/write permission on file store folder. Its also essential that file store gets backed up regularly (just like database).

Comment: i have created a folder outside the web directory and the issue still exists, all the file operations is carried out,, ie files get moved to trash folder,db status is updated but IIS hangs and restart... may be some other issue...exist can u suggest any information regarding such issues while handling many/large files

Comment: @deepu, what happens if you attempt to delete smaller set of smaller file size (say one file of few KBs) - do you see the same issue? If yes then the issue will not be related to file size. As such, I don't think that 35-40 MB files are large - how much time does it take to delete those files? What is the code for deleting the files?

Comment: its not with size issue..i just tried to delete some 100 files totally around 4mb then also same issue came. it just took 1-2 mints to clear all the files. May be there is any limit for number of files to be modified in server..

Comment: @deepu, perhaps, issue will be present even if you try to delete a single file (why not try it). Are you 100% certain that you are not deleting any file or folder under web directory or virtual directory (physical location would be outside web directory but logically under web site).

Comment: issue exist when file no: increases ie more than 30- 40 files. when i delete small no: of files nothing weird happened.. it was working fine.. i'm not deleting any file i just moved it from upload folder to trash folder. using File.move()

Comment: @Deepu, moving is equivalent to delete in this context because files are changing under web directory. You see the particular behavior because the worker process recycles only after n number of file changes (n is a configurable value in app/machine config). Some changes (bin folder of config file change) can trigger immediate recycling.

Comment: so IIS recycles after changes happen to n number of files.how is it possible to manage with the issue.

Comment: @Deepu - its n number of file/folder changes *within web directory*. Hence the advise to move file upload store outside web directory.

Comment: this issue is not yet solved. I think it exist on IIS 7 only. Our online testing server in which is not IIS 7 has no problem. Is there any security issue with such actions taking place in IIS 7.

Comment: the issue is not yet solved feel free to post your answers or any idea that could help out... The below link seems to show the answer of the issue i posted here..but my case was when i deleted or copy the files there was no errors while uploading..

http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2010/09/01/uploadify-iis7/

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution: decouple your session state from your process by using SQL Server as a state manager or using the ASP.Net State Manager service. This will require that all of your session objects are serializable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx (See Session Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

old post, but found a solution on an other forum for who still ends up here after searching...

http://forums.asp.net/p/1144478/1849837.aspx

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
object o = p.GetValue(null, null);

FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
object monitor = f.GetValue(o);

MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

..and add it to a good place, such as Application_Start in global.asax

You must add "using System.Reflection" to Global.asax.cs